# How to create a specified number of columns in a data grid from text box wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, textbox

I want to be able to write a number (preferably only from 1-10) in a textbox and create that certain number of columns for it in a data grid. How would I be able to do that? This is what I've got so far:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="345" Margin="244,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="528" Background="Transparent" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" RowBackground="#202020" AlternatingRowBackground="#262626">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Words" Binding="{Binding Keywords}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Colour" Binding="{Binding Colour}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

That is my grid that I have, which on the click of a button simply reads the data from a series of textboxes. Then I have the textbox I want that will be able to modify the number of columns the datagrid creates:

```
<TextBox x:Name="noColumns" Height="26" Margin="88,244,663.6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I have no idea on how to make it so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your started on the right track.

First you need to capture the number entered into the `TextBox`. Let's use the `LostFocus` event in this example.

```
//Add LostFocuse Event Handler
//Your other properties have been removed for the sake of example brevity
<TextBox x:Name="noColumns" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

Ok, now let's extract the number from the textbox, and dynamically create columns for your datagrid.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int columns;

    //Determine if TextBox text is number. If so, add columns
    if (int.TryParse(noColumns.Text, out columns))
    {
         for(int x=1; x<=columns; x++)
         {
              //Add column with header.
              Tasks.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = string.Format("COL: {0}", x) });
         }
    }
}
```